# Modifying wpa_Supplicant TB-X304F_

Tags: android, android-wifi, tablet, wpa-supplicant

I have 285 different networks between the different campus apartments for which I am trying to add network profile information to a series of Lenovo Tab4 10 TB-X304F so they may connect without having our Apartment Managers carry around a list of wifi passwords.

So far, I have created a custom wpa_supplicant.conf file with all of the network blocks for each of the networks across the campus. I have rooted the device. I have pushed this custom file to /sdcard/TWRP. I then copied the file from /sdcard/TWRP to /data/misc/wifi.

Now we run into my issue, it appears that this file is stored in at least 3 locations which I have currently found, /etc/wifi, /system/etc/wifi and /data/misc/wifi. The other part of the problem is that these files appear to be rewritten/overwritten on boot.

Which of these file locations should I be updating with my custom wpa_supplicant.conf file? How do I stop the file from being rebuilt on boot? Or, how do I make the process, which builds the file on boot, build it with the networks I want added?

Am I missing any other steps?

I have also tried running " wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/sdcard/TWRP/wpa_supplicant.conf -B " as a command in the adb shell with super user permissions and didn't receive any output or confirmation. What am I misunderstanding about the wpa_supplicant command?

Just in case here are the settings currently in /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf which I have copied into my custom file:

```
ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets
disable_scan_offload=1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
update_config=1
device_name=LenovoTB-X304F
manufacturer=LENOVO
model_name=Lenovo TB-X304F
model_number=Lenovo TB-X304F
serial_number=<SerialNumber>
device_type=10-0050F204-5
config_methods=physical_display virtual_push_button
p2p_disabled=1
pmf=1
external_sim=1
tdls_external_control=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know much, but I can successfully edit/replace

```
   /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

provided that (1) I have the device in Aeroplane Mode and (2) I make sure that the file belongs to user "system" and group "wifi", and has permissions 660. If I forget (1) or (2), somehow the file reverts later to the one before editing/replacing or is reinitialized to virtually empty (I am not sure when either happened exactly, but I noticed both cases). I believe your use of TWRP is effectively equivalent to my use of Aeroplane Mode--but I am not aware that you can "chown" a file in TWRP. I never had to touch any of the other locations where the file can apparently be found.

For reference, the commands to get the right ownership and permissions should be

```
   chmod 660 /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
   chown system:wifi /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Of course, all this needs one to be root.

Comment: ...this worked for me perfectly. Activated airplane mode, sent updated wpa_supplicant.conf file to /data/misc/wifi/ and did .\adb shell su -c 'chmod 660 /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf'
.\adb shell su -c 'chown system:wifi /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf'